# Specify list of gems to install

Tags: rubygems, npm

`npm` has the `package.json` file to specify which node modules to install. That will be automatically be used by this command:

```
npm install
```

pip has `requirements.txt` to specify python modules to install. It can be used like this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Is there a similar command for gems? Is there a way of doing:

```
gem install -i my-gems.json
```

Or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) that do this.